# Hadoop install zookeeper error

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, apache-zookeeper

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and Hadoop 2.5

at `start-dfs.sh` and `start-yarn.sh` all the nodes show up once `jps` is executed

When I look at my logs

```
  hadoop-hduser-datanode-stratageeks-DL-E35LM1-R2.log
  hadoop-hduser-namenode-stratageeks-DL-E35LM1-R2.log
  hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-stratageeks-DL-E35LM1-R2.log
```

All three have one thing in common

```
  ...
  ...
  2014-09-30 09:04:06,282 WARN org.mortbay.log: Failed to read file: /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar
  java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:154)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:118)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.TagLibConfiguration.configureWebApp(TagLibConfiguration.java:174)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1279)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.start(HttpServer2.java:827)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.initialize(SecondaryNameNode.java:276)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.<init>(SecondaryNameNode.java:192)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.main(SecondaryNameNode.java:671)
```

I have given hduser full permissions over zookeeper jar, but still the same warning.

**Why am I doubting?
Because my Active nodes are still 0 even though the `jps` tells me everything is working. And all of my mapreduce jobs are freezing at the start,the ResourceManager is obviously not finding any resources.**

Comment: what is the output of jps?

Comment: @AntarikshaYelkawar - I get all Nodes displayed, datanode, namenode, secondary, jps and resourcemanager, etc

Comment: download a new copy of the jar and replace the old one with it